# Вывод гласных, которые есть в строке. C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, строки

Хочу вывести количество каждой гласной буквы которая есть в строке и общее количество гласных. Не понимаю почему метод sentance.Count(s => vowels.Contains(ch)); выводит количество всех символов строки.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<char> vowels = new List<char> {'а','о','ы','и','у','э','ё','я','е','ю'};
            string sentance = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            int allvowels = 0;
            foreach (char ch in sentance)
            {
                int vowelcount = 0;
                if (vowels.Contains(ch))
                {
                    allvowels++;
                    vowelcount = sentance.Count(s => vowels.Contains(ch));
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ch} = {vowelcount}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(allvowels+" общее количество гласных");
           
                
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: `vowels.Contains(s)`?

Comment: Вы проходите по каждому символу, и на каждой итерации вызывается метод  **vowels.Contains(ch)** , который проверяет наличие символа в массиве, по которому вы идете.

Answer (score 2):

> vowelcount = sentance.Count(s => vowels.Contains(ch));

vowelcount = sentance.Count(s=>s.Equals(ch));